# Official List of Perks for Fallout: New Vegas

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

Does anyone know the list for all perks in Fallout: New Vegas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Gamebanshee has the full list of perks](http://www.gamebanshee.com/falloutnewvegas/perks.php). They're sorted by the level at which they unlock. Just select from the list on the right hand side.

In addition, there are [Traits](http://www.gamebanshee.com/falloutnewvegas/traits.php), which are similar to Perks, but can only be selected at character creation (limit 2), and which have a negative side-effect in addition to their bonuses.

Answer (score 4):

[The Vault](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout:_New_Vegas_perks) has a small list of perks but not a full list.

Comment: Definitely looks like a full list to me.